# MySQL Issue with combined SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two primary SELECT statements that return the desired results when run individually, but when combined, don't return the desired result.

**Query 1**

This works fine, returning the expected result.

```
SELECT feed_mode_id FROM user WHERE id=2;
+--------------+
| feed_mode_id |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

**Query 2**

This is also fine. Sometimes the result will be empty, sometimes not.

```
SELECT
        answer.id AS answer_id
    FROM
        answer
    WHERE
        answer.question_id = (
            SELECT
                question.id
            FROM
                question
            ORDER BY
                datetime_added_utc DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        AND answer.user_id = 2;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**Query 1 and 2 combined**

When combining these into two sub-SELECT statements as shown below, `feed_mode_id` is `NULL`, but the result for `x.feed_mode_id` should be as shown in Query 1. This is my lack of understanding as to how these kind of combined statements work.

```
SELECT
    x.feed_mode_id,
    IF (COUNT(y.answer_id) < 1, 0, 1) AS answered_question
FROM
    (SELECT
        user.feed_mode_id
    FROM
        user
    WHERE
        user.id = 2) AS x,
    (SELECT
        answer.id AS answer_id
    FROM
        answer
    WHERE
        answer.question_id = (
            SELECT
                question.id
            FROM
                question
            ORDER BY
                datetime_added_utc DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        AND answer.user_id = 2) AS y

+--------------+-------------------+
| feed_mode_id | answered_question |
+--------------+-------------------+
|         NULL |                 0 |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

Why is `feed_mode_id` producing `NULL` and not `1`? I'm open to different approaches to re-writing the query altogether as well. The desired result would be:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| feed_mode_id | answered_question |
+--------------+-------------------+
|            1 |                 0 |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

This is somehow related to the fact that Query 2's result is empty for this case. For cases where Query 2 returns a value (not empty) then the combined query works as desired.

Comment: Can you tell me what result you want to achieve after the query executes?

Comment: *feed_mode_id* is a column name not a table name. You are trying to select from a column instead of a table.

Comment: Hi Hasib. For the first subquery, I am selecting from `x`, which is a derived table with one column and one value. Can you explain what you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: (I don't understand the comment from Hasib, it doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Cartesian product between `x` and `y`. As long as each of those rowsources return only one row, the query will return a single row.

I recommend you ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.

Also, it's not clear why you need inline views and subqueries, apart from the subquery that returns that "most recently added" question.

I'm not entirely clear what resultset you are actually attempting to return, but it looks like you are determining whether a particular user (uniquely identified by the "id" column of the "user" table), has provided an "answer" to the "most recently added question".

If that's the result you are trying to return, I believe this query will return that result:

```
SELECT u.feed_mode_id
     , IF( COUNT(a.id) < 1, 0, 1) AS answered_question
  FROM ( SELECT q.id
           FROM question q
          ORDER BY q.datetime_added_utc DESC, q.id DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) r
  JOIN user u
    ON u.id = 2
  LEFT
  JOIN answer a
    ON a.user_id = u.id
   AND a.question_id = r.id
 GROUP BY u.id
```

---

NOTES: The inline view aliased as `r` return the `id` of the "most recently added" `question`. (In the original query, if two or more question have the same `datetime_added_utc`, it's indeterminate which row will be returned. This query makes it determinate by adding another expression to the ORDER BY clause. (The inline view query could be pulled out and run separately, to verify it's returning the expected result.)

The row returned from `r` (if there is one) is then joined to a row retrieved from the "user" table `u`. We're assuming here that the `id` column in the "user" table is a unique identifier, and likely the primary key of the "user" table.

If we have a "most recently added" question (i.e. a row from `r`), and there's a row from "user" that matches the `u.id=2` predicate in the `ON` clause, then so far, we are guaranteed that the query is going to return a single row.

Next, we perform an "outer join" operation, to find matching rows from the "answer" table. The predicates in the `ON` clause restrict the rows returned to only those that have a `user_id` matching the `id` from `u` (in this example, equivalent to specifying `a.user_id=2`, *and* having a `question_id` that matches the `id` of the "most recently added" question `r`.

The `LEFT` keyword identifies this as an "outer join"; if there are no matching rows from the "answer" table, then the query will still return the row from `r` and `u`. (If this were an inner join, that is, if we removed the `LEFT` keyword, then if there were no matching rows from the "answer" table, then the query would not return a row.)

We add a `GROUP BY u.id` clause, in case we get more than one matching row from `answer`; the `GROUP BY` causes all rows that have the same value of u.id to be collapsed into a single row.

The `COUNT()` aggregate counts the number of non-null occurrences of the `id` from the "answer" table. If there were no matching rows found, then a.id will be NULL, so COUNT(a.id) will return 0.

---

This same query would also work if we were looking for multipler users, if we specified multiple values for user.id to match, e.g.

```
 ON u.id IN (2,3,5,7)
```

or also if we left that predicate off entirely, so we got a row back for *every* user. This query would still work.

But in either of those cases, we'd also want to add `u.id AS user_id` to the SELECT list of the query, so we would know which row was for which user.

If we wanted to return the *two* most recently added questions, we could change the LIMIT clause in `r`, and then add `r.id` to the `GROUP BY` clause. Again, we'd then likely also want to return `r.id AS question_id` in the SELECT list, so we knew which row was for which question.

Comment: Hi Spencer. Exactly right, seeing if the user has answered the most recent question is what this is seeking. I didn't even know that technically I was doing a JOIN, just with different syntax. Interesting. I'll be learning a lot from this explanation. The query looks efficient and works beautifully. This is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: TPoy: the comma syntax is what we used to use, a LONG time ago... `SELECT ... FROM b,a WHERE a.id = b.a_id`, back before the `JOIN` keyword was introduced. Just replace that comma with the keyword `JOIN`, and optionally, relocate the predicate in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. (In this simple example, just replace `WHERE` with `ON`.   `SELECT ... FROM b JOIN a ON b.id = a.b_id`. That's just newer syntax for the same query.  (The comma syntax is still supported, so old queries still run. But even old timers like me have learned the newer syntax.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know that. And as for derived tables, I use a lot of them in other queries. Now I have the urge to go back and re-write a lot of other queries in the system, which is a good thing. All in due time. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome. Just to clarify, it's not that "derived tables" are to be avoided like the plague; they can be very useful. Sometimes, using a derived table makes it possible to return a result that wouldn't otherwise be possible, and sometimes, derived tables _improve_ query performance. But using them where they aren't needed, especially with *large* sets, can also introduce some significant performance issues.

Comment: That's the one principle I try to keep in mind: avoid them if possible if they return large sets.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly query

```
SELECT
    x.feed_mode_id,
    IF (COUNT(y.answer_id) < 1, 0, 1) AS answered_question
FROM
    (SELECT
        user.feed_mode_id
    FROM
        user
    WHERE
        user.id = 2) AS x,
    (SELECT
        answer.id AS answer_id
    FROM
        answer
    WHERE
        answer.question_id IN (
            SELECT
                question.id
            FROM
                question
            ORDER BY
                datetime_added_utc DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        AND answer.user_id = 2) AS y
```

> answer.question_id = to answer.question_id IN

Comment: Thank you bluesky. I attempted (simply changing `answer.question_id =` to `answer.question_id IN`) but it's not supported. I'm using 5.5.37. The result: `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Do Your MYSQL support JOIN ??, if yes, you can JOIN to get result

Comment: And even if that was supported, replacing `=` with `IN`, it wouldn't change the query any. (It's the LIMIT 1 in the subquery that makes it possible to use the equality comparison; if that subquery returned more than one row, MySQL would throw a different error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to answer my own question, but I found a solution that works. I've moved the IF statement to the sub-SELECT rather than the primary SELECT. I don't know why this works and the previous attempt doesn't, but it's producing the desired result now.

```
SELECT
    x.feed_mode_id,
    y.question_answered 
FROM
    (SELECT
        user.feed_mode_id
    FROM
        user
    WHERE
        user.id = 2) AS x,
    (SELECT
        IF (COUNT(answer.id < 1), 1, 0) AS question_answered 
    FROM
        answer
    WHERE
        answer.question_id = (
            SELECT
                question.id
            FROM
                question
            ORDER BY
                datetime_added_utc DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        AND answer.user_id = 2) AS y;

+--------------+-------------------+
| feed_mode_id | question_answered |
+--------------+-------------------+
|            1 |                 0 |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This query seems way more involved than is required to return the specified resultset. There is overhead with materializing each of the derived tables; true, those are small tables, and they are going to fit in memory, so we're not going to notice a performance issue, but we tend to avoid derived tables when there isn't some benefit. See my answer for a different query that returns the result I believe you are looking for. (Absent some sample data, knowledge of uniqueness and nullability of the columns, I'm just guessing.

Comment: I had the feeling this was doing more work than necessary, though my thinking is still somewhat brute force with SQL. Thanks for your excellent explanation.